# Why doesn't PyCharm unit-test discovery work on directories?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm, python-unittest

When I right-click on a test module (file) and choose `Run Unittests in ...`, PyCharm does this, using its test-GUI.

When I right-click on a package (directory) with some test modules, PCcharm knows that unit tests exists--it shows the `Run Unittests in ...` menu item. But then PyCharm fails to find any tests.

(My directory `testing` has just `__init__.py  utils_test.py` in it. The latter has `class UtilTest(TestCase)` in it.)

Output:

```
Launching unittests with arguments python -m unittest discover-s /home/joshua/PycharmProjects/myproj/proj/testing  -t in /home/joshua/PycharmProjects/myproj/proj/testing 

Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

I can create a suite and run it manually, but I want the benefit of PyCharm's testing GUI for comparing actual and expected, etc.

How can I get it to discover my unit tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyCharm test-discovery only finds test-files whose names begin `test`. My test files (like `util_test.py`) had  `test` at the end